# How to create button with rails that add input fields with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, button

What is the best practice to create a button with a rails form_helper that will generate through Javascript/JQuery new input fields ?

(This button is supposed to be used within a form with nested objects)

N.B. : My app is actually running with rails 3.2, but I want it to be compatible with rails 4 and 5.

**=== EDIT ===**

My nested objects need a much more complex handling than rails's "accepts_nested_attributes_for" and Ryan Bates "nested_form" gem are able to deal with. I'm looking for best pratice with rails only helpers without use of specific gems for nested model, but JQuery

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you are looking for a solution to add nested fields for a nested model inside a form.

You have a great gem by Ryan Bates:
https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Im using it in a rails 4.1 application and it works great!

Follow the instructions in the github page - its really easy to install and to use.

You can also take a look in the railscasts videos:

[196-nested-model-form-part-1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

[197-nested-model-form-part-2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

(The gem in not maintained anymore, but its working in my rails 4 app. I'm not sure about rails 5 app)

Comment: I know this gem, but sorry, my nested objects need a much more complex handling than "accepts_nested_attributes_for " and Ryan Bates nested_form gem are able to deal with. I'm looking for rails only helper without use of specific gems for nested model, but JQuery.

Comment: @Douglas, ok :) so you can take a look in the javascript code of the nested_form gem, and get an idea of how to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice not exist  ,you can create a button with css or react or js, the best practice depending of your needing.

Comment: First : I know there is a best practice with "Unobtrusive javascript". Then I'm looking for Rails helpers. A really simple example.